# TI-BASIC: Indexing to Prompt or Input command

Tags: list, vector, prompt, ti-basic, n-dimensional

I have a TI-84 Plus, and I am creating a program to calculate the magnitude of an n-dimensional vector. I have included my code and its output below.

**Program Editor:**

```
PROGRAM:NTHDMAG
Disp "HOW MANY DIMENSIONS?"
Prompt N
{X,Y,Z,T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,L,M,P,U,V,W}->L1
For(K,1,N,1)
L1(K)->Q
Prompt Q
End
```

**Output Display:**

```
pgrmNTHDMAG
HOW MANY DIMENSIONS?
N=?3
Q=?1
Q=?2
Q=?3
Done
```

I want the Q's to be replaced with each letter in L1, and indexing L1(K) in the Prompt command throws an error.  The values for the L1 letters will be whatever the value of each component is (so here, for example, 1i + 2j + 3k).

I hope this is clear, but I am more than willing to clarify if it is not. Thank you for any help that you can provide!

Comment: `Input` allows custom strings to be displayed, but is this really what you need in the first place? User could enter a list themselves with the usual `{A,B,C` syntax (this also enables using `Rcl` with an existing list which may be convenient), of course then `N` is not predetermined

Comment: @harold I could have the user input a string, but that's less user friendly and I don't want that. I mean I can if I have to, but I would prefer to present one variable at a time.

Comment: `Input` allows a custom string to be *displayed* (and read as input too but that's not the point). That's what you're trying to do, right? Replace "Q=?" by a custom string?

Comment: @harold Yes that is correct and that is what I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're trying to do,

```
Prompt N
0->dim(|LT
For(I,1,N
    Input sub("XYZTABCDEFGHIJLMPUVW",I,1)+"=?",X
    X->|LT(I)
End
Disp |LT
DelVar |LT
```

[image]

`Input` is used instead of `Prompt`, allowing us to choose the string. The string is built by taking a single-letter substring from `"XYZTABCDEFGHIJLMPUVW"` and then appending `"=?"` to it, making it look just like `Prompt`, of course this is easy to change. It's SourceCoder syntax so `|L` means that strange small ∟ for list names. Does not work if list T is archived, it could be made to work but IMO it should not, usually an archived list means the user wants to keep it.

It's much easier to let the user enter a list themselves though, for example

```
Input "Input List:",|LT
Disp |LT
DelVar |LT
```

This allows more convenient user input such as `Rcl` (of a whole list) and list operations, for example:

[image]

Or perhaps more typical:

[image]

But `N` is not explicit.

Leaving the result in `Ans` is probably useful. Implicitly printing by evaluating a value instead of a proper command on the last line gets rid of `Done` which isn't that useful, but it's something you can do.

```
Input "Input List:",|LT
sqrt(sum(|LT^^2
DelVar |LT
Ans
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have one follow up question: since the list is declared inside the for loop, will I be able to call the variables created by the user elsewhere in my code?

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast yes, variables are global and not even declared as such, it is `0->dim(|LT` that would create the list if it did not exist

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast though if you meant variable X, Y, Z etc.. it does not work like that, the result is in a list here. There is no reasonable way to assign to a "variable variable" (as in most languages for that matter).

Comment: Also, how do you get the symbols "sub" and "|" on the calculator?

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast `sub(` is in the catalog, go to T and press up twice. `|L` is the small L for list names, go to LIST, OPS, press up.

Comment: Also, just for my own curiosity, how did you get the calculator screens into the answer? It's cool!

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast I used [SourceCoder](https://www.cemetech.net/sc/), it has an emulator that can record the screen like this